# platform.registerBackButtonAction() not working when build --prod

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am working on the project using ionic 3.

`ionic cordova run android` i use this command to run app.

in this operation `platform.registerBackButtonAction()` is working fine..

However, if I use the `ionic cordova run android --prod` option, `platform.registerBackButtonAction ()` is not working.

any help is appreciated.

below is my code for handling hardware back button.

```
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    let view = this.nav.getActive();
    if(view.component.name == "NonetworkPage"){
      if (!this.showedAlert) {
        this.confirmExitApp();
      } else {
        this.showedAlert = false;
        this.confirmAlert.dismiss();
      }
    }else{
      if (view.component.name == "HomePage") {
        if (!this.showedAlert) {
          this.confirmExitApp();
        } else {
          this.showedAlert = false;
          this.confirmAlert.dismiss();
        }
      } else if (view.component.name != "HomePage" && view.component.name != "LoginPage") {
        if (this.nav.length() == 1) {
          this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
        } else if (this.nav.length() > 1) {
          this.nav.pop();
        }
      } else if (view.component.name == "LoginPage") {
        this.confirmExitApp();
      }
    }
  });
```

and below is for confirmation exit popup

```
 confirmExitApp() {
    this.showedAlert = true;
    this.confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "Exit App?",
      message: "Are you sure you want to exit App?",
      enableBackdropDismiss: true,
      cssClass: 'confirmCustomCss',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'No',
          handler: () => {
            this.showedAlert = false;
            return;
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          handler: () => {
            this.platform.exitApp();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    this.confirmAlert.present();
  }
```

Comment: Try to activate the logs : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-console/
then catch the error!

Comment: found the solution.Thanks for help buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
         let view = this.nav.getActive();
         let currentRootPage = view.component; 
        if(currentRootPage == MyPage)
});
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Because prod flag minify our code and also obfuscate page names but you can fix this problem by using this code may hope it will helps you and it will run on both build --prod and build

```
 platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    let view = this.navCtrl.getActive();
    let page = view ? this.navCtrl.getActive().instance : null;
    if (page && (page instanceof Mypage)
```

Don't forget to import Mypage into app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I also found the solution and it work fine.                                                                                                   
                                                                            
           `this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {                                                                                                        
            let view = this.nav.getActive();
            let currentRootPage = view.component;
             if(currentRootPage == MyPage)`

Answer (score 0):

in ionic 3 this gives the name of current page:

```
const currentActivePage = this.nav.getActive().id;
```

And it can be compared by

```
if(currentActivePage == 'LoginPage')
```

Comment: I think the asker already found a solution based on last comments, and I don't see how your answer is helping since the code you provided was already given in the sample he posted... Sorry if I missed something, in such a case please elaborate your answer.